# Can't make Android in-app billing sample app to work

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I've tried to get the in-app billing sample app to work according to the steps in http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download.

I will specify everything I've done + added logs at the end.
I hope someone will be able to tell me what I am doing wrong.

**Here is everything I did** (I know it's long... but I wanted to make sure I did not forget anything):

I imported the Dungeons project into my workspace and my Google public key to Security.java's base64EncodedPublicKey variable.
I got that public key from a new app I added to my Google Developer account.

I changed the name of the application package as requested so it does not have the com.example prefix

I build the app and signed in Via "Android Tools" -> "Export Signed Application Package..."

I uploaded that APK to the new app I created in my developer account (the one from which I took the public key)

I added in app product to the new app, with the same IDs as in the Dungeons project (sword_001 , postion_001) and activated them.

I added a test account to my developer account in "Settings" -> "Gmail accounts with testing access"
That account is NOT the my developer account, but a new one I created.

I installed the signed app on a device, which I factory reseted and logged in with the test account I added to my developer account.

**My device**

I installed the app on an android 2.3.4 device with no SIM card (this is my testing device). 
Google play version: 3.10.9

**Results**

When I try to buy one of the products, I get an "item not available" error (I get it twice actually).
I tried setting DEBUG to true, and now I get "error retrieving information from server. [RPC:S-5:AEC-0]" (twice...)

**Logs:**

```
12-06 07:58:42.255: D/Finsky(1955): [7] MarketBillingService.getPreferredAccount: com.sakal.billingtest.merchant: Account from first account.
12-06 07:58:42.275: D/Finsky(1955): [7] MarketBillingService.getPreferredAccount: com.sakal.billingtest.merchant: Account from first account.
12-06 07:58:42.325: D/Finsky(1955): [27] MarketBillingService.getPreferredAccount: com.sakal.billingtest.merchant: Account from first account.
12-06 07:58:42.335: D/Finsky(1955): [27] MarketBillingService.getPreferredAccount: com.sakal.billingtest.merchant: Account from first account.
12-06 07:58:42.991: E/Volley(1955): [15] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/details?doc=subs:com.sakal.billingtest.merchant:potion_001
12-06 07:58:44.785: D/Finsky(1955): [1] MarketBillingService.sendResponseCode: Sending response RESULT_ERROR for request 8273178932293834331 to com.sakal.billingtest.merchant.
12-06 07:58:44.785: I/BillingService(3173): handleCommand() action: com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE
12-06 07:58:45.551: E/Volley(1955): [14] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/details?doc=inapp:com.sakal.billingtest.merchant:potion_001
12-06 07:58:46.225: D/Finsky(1955): [1] MarketBillingService.sendResponseCode: Sending response RESULT_ERROR for request 2493329704825383333 to com.sakal.billingtest.merchant.
12-06 07:58:46.245: I/BillingService(3173): handleCommand() action: com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE
```

Comment: Have you uploaded the project on your developer console as Draft? Are the version codes in the Manifest the same as uploaded application?

Comment: Yes, I uploaded it as a draft. and I do not run the app from eclipse to my device, I installed the signed app (the same apk I uploaded to the draft), so they must have the same version code

Comment: Hey I 'm getting same error just started before few minutes...

Comment: May be some update operation going with Google Play server or anything else?

Comment: Check the price, it should be > 0.00, also when you try to send the request too often, such error could occur. So maybe you should wait some time before trying again.

Comment: @Demonick : In my case I'm using sample app of in-app in my application.so of course it may not be an issue about price.

Comment: the price I set is valid...

Comment: OK, problem solved. It was only a matter of time... I guess it took Google's servers a while to update my additions to the developer account, but now it works and I can finally buy a potion from myself.

Answer (score 2):

OK, problem solved.
It was only a matter of time... I guess it took Google's servers a while to update my additions to the developer account, but now it works and I can finally buy a potion from myself.

Now there are new problems.

1. when I select an item to buy, I first get an "Item not found" error, and when I click "ok" I see the product in google play. does this happen to anyone else?
2. I purchased several new items, I see on my google checkout account that the order is "shipped"  BUT in the billing test app, under "Items you own" I don't see anything...
3. in http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download they suggest to

> refund purchases that are made with test accounts, otherwise the purchases will show up as actual payouts to your merchant account

where can I perform the refund? in my google checkout account the "Refund some money" item is greyed out...

Does anyone know how to handle these issues?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your post will get deleted. Only answers are allowed here. So better post your question as a new one ;)

Comment: I opened a new question... can't I delete this answer?

Comment: no need, just delete the new questions but leave the "ok ..." problem solution in, so people know they only have to wait for a few hours.

Comment: @dors i had made one product on consol now i am going to test it  but when i test from device it's display me sample title and price is 0.99$ can you tell me why this proble arise i had product with name pro version but it's display me sample title